# How to type special letter with Pyautogui

Tags: python

I been trying to enter special letters such as ä, ö, ï,etc using pyautogui without any luck.

I have tried a combination of hotkey, keydown, keyup, etc...

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please share some code

Comment: import pyautogui
# â is ok with
pyautogui.hotkey('^', 'a')

# ä is NOT ok with
pyautogui.hotkey('¨', 'a')

Comment: please edit your post and add the code

Comment: I get the "Page not found" when I want to edit the post. Sorry